# Simple way to typeset vector going in and out of the plane in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, vector

Is there a way to easy achieve this result? 
Something like the symbol recommended from wikipedia but with the dot of the vector bigger.

[image]

And is it possibile to do that in `\tikzset` ,I was triyng something like

```
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={draw, circle}}
    \node[mystyle] (nodename) {} ;
```

But this draws only the circle around... I was surprised not to find anything, so maybe this is a possible duplicate.

Comment: Depends on what the context is, but if you just want the symbols, then `$\odot\otimes$`.

Comment: I want some more "controllable", like the answer of @marmot, so that i can modify width and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. One option is to use `pic`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
   pics/.cd,
   vector out/.style={
      code={
         \draw[#1] (0,0)  circle (1) (45:1) -- (225:1) (135:1) -- (315:1);
      }%end code   
   }%end style
}%end tikzset
\tikzset{
   pics/.cd,
   vector in/.style={
      code={
        \draw[#1] (0,0)  circle (1);
        \fill[#1] (0,0)  circle (.1);
      }%end code   
   }%end style
}%end tikzset
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\path (0,0)  pic {vector out={line width=1.5pt}} (3,0)  pic {vector in={line
width=1.5pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: With relative line widths:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
   pics/.cd,
   vector out/.style args={#1/#2}{
      code={
         \draw[#1] (0,0)  circle (1);
         \draw[#2] (45:1) -- (225:1) (135:1) -- (315:1);
      }%end code   
   }%end style
}%end tikzset
\tikzset{
   pics/vector in/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{
      code={
        \draw[line width=#1] (0,0)  circle (1);
        \fill[#2] (0,0)  circle (#3);
      }%end code   
   }%end style
}%end tikzset
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\path (0,0)  pic {vector out={line width=3pt/line width=2pt}} (3,0)  
pic {vector in=1.5pt/blue/.2};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution, is there also the possibility to control the width of the `x` lines, other than the width of the circle?

Comment: @opisthofulax Yes, please have a look at my update.

Answer (score 4):

A `path picture` is another option, or the less flexible option of plonking `\odot` and `\otimes` in `node contents`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
odot/.style={
  circle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  node contents={$\odot$},
  scale=2
},
otimes/.style={
  circle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  node contents={$\otimes$},
  scale=2
},
circ/.style={
  circle,
  draw,
  minimum size=5mm,
  inner sep=0
},
odot2/.style={
  circ,
  path picture={\fill circle[radius=2pt];}
},
otimes2/.style={
  circ,
  path picture={
   \draw (path picture bounding box.45) -- (path picture bounding box.225);
   \draw (path picture bounding box.135) -- (path picture bounding box.315);
  }
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [odot,name=o1];
\node [otimes,name=o2,at={(1,0)}];
\node [odot2] at (2,0) {};
\node [otimes2] at (3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, Your solution is nice too, hard choice, but I had to make it :(